# Google calendar events do not show with approval prompt("auto")

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am listing Google events in my own calendar. Everything worked fine, until I changed `approval_prompt` to `auto` from `force`. I certainly do not need refresh token every time user logs in (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm new to Google API).

Another strange thing is that I can still create, update, delete all events. It simply does not list Google calendar events.

Here is the code:

login.php

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

$client->setScopes(array(
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
    ));

$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
```

calendar.php:

```
var events = [];
<?php

            foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
            $now = new DateTime();
            $unformatted_start = new DateTime($event->start->dateTime);
            $start = $event->start->dateTime;
            $end = $event->end->dateTime;
            $allDay = false;
            if (($event->getStart()->getDate())!= NULL) {
                $start = (new DateTime($event->getStart()->getDate()))->format('Y/m/d');
                $end = (new DateTime($event->getEnd()->getDate()))->format('Y/m/d');
                $allDay = true;
            }
            $summary =$event->getSummary();
            $event_url = $event->getHtmlLink();
            $is_matching = false;
            foreach ($allEventIds as $id) {
               //id->e_google_id above in the file
               if($event->getId()==$id->e_google_id){
                    $is_matching = true;
                    break;
               }
            }
            if(!$is_matching){ 
            ?>            


events.push({title:"<?php echo $summary;?>",start:"<?php echo $start;?>",end:"<?php echo $end;?>",color: "<?php if($now>$unformatted_start){echo '#f3867e';}else {echo '#F44336';}?>",textColor: 'white', url:"<?php echo $event_url;?>", allDay:"<?php echo $allDay;?>" })        
<?php }}
?>
```

Comment: If ApprovalPrompt('auto') user will be seen consent screen for given set os scopes for the first time. later they wont see this screen until new scopes are added/deleted. But if ApprovalPrompt('force') then the user sees a consent page even if they previously gave consent to your application. You should change ApprovalPrompt to "force" and setAccessType to "online". If you select offline, you are requesting for refresh token. Also, please post the error code you are getting for events.list

Comment: I guess I found the issue:
I thought that posting `if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $client)` was unnecessary, but that was the problem, because I do not get refresh token on login